# jni cannot receive jstring contains '\0' correctly

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

**in jni:**

```
jstring JNICALL native_encrypt(JNIEnv* env, jstring plainstr) {
    if(plainstr == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    const char* plain_str = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, plainstr, NULL);
    LOG_ERROR("plain_str:%s", plain_str);
    int i=0;
    int n = strlen(plain_str);
    //android_log
    LOG_ERROR("plain_str len=%d", n);
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        LOG_ERROR("%d", plain_str[i]);
    }
    jstring encryptedstr = encrypt(env, plain_str);
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, plainstr, plain_str);

    return encryptedstr;
}
```

**in java(android)**

```
String js = "abc\0def\0a0123456789";
System.out.println("jstring=" + js + ", LEN=" + js.length() + ", " + Arrays.toString(js.getBytes(Charset.forName("utf-8"))));
System.out.println("encrypt jstring=" + native_encrypt(js));
```

**the output of java is**

> jstring=abc��def��a0123456789, LEN=19, [97, 98, 99, 0, 100, 101, 102, 0, 97, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57]

**the output of jni is**

> plain_str:abc��def��a0123456789
>       plain_str len=21
>       97
>       98
>       99
>       192
>       128
>       100
>       101
>       102
>       192
>       128
>       97
>       48
>       49
>       50
>       51
>       52
>       53
>       54
>       55
>       56
>       57

the '\0' is changed to two chars: 192,128. WHY ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#GetStringUTFChars

> GetStringUTFChars [...] Returns a pointer to an array of bytes representing the string in modified UTF-8 encoding

And: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Modified_UTF-8

> In Modified UTF-8 (MUTF-8),[29] the null character (U+0000) uses the two-byte overlong encoding 11000000 10000000 (hexadecimal C0 80), instead of 00000000 (hexadecimal 00). Modified UTF-8 strings never contain any actual null bytes but can contain all Unicode code points including U+0000,[30] which allows such strings (with a null byte appended) to be processed by traditional null-terminated string functions.